# how to install libmysqld-dev on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, package-management

When I enter the command:

`sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev`

I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... 
Done Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the 
unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: libmysqld-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient-dev (>= 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: See this answer it could [help with the unmet dependencies problem.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) . The error points to something to do with your mysql installation.

Comment: What happens if you try: `sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev libmysqlclient-dev=5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1`? You can try it without a specific version string, too. Keep going down this path until you get a useful error message.